# ¿Cómo contar la cantidad de tweets que traigo de Twitter?

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de contar la cantidad de tweets que recibo de Twitter. ¿Qué función puedo usar? Tengo 2 bucles, uno para fechas y otro para palabras buscadas. Quiero contarlos individualmente, esto es, "el número de tweets que incluyen 'xxxx' del 'aaaa-mm-dd'"
Lo ideal seria tener la cantidad de tweets por fecha, y dentro de esta rama, ordenarlos por palabra buscada.
Mi codigo es el siguiente,

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import GetOldTweets3 as got
import pandas as pd



keywords = ['saqueo chile', 'vandalismo chile', 'delincuencia chile','ataque carabinero', 'ataque comisaria','ataque subcomisaria',' manifestacion chile', 'protesta chile', 'bomba molotov','coctel molotov', 'funa chile', 'incendio intencional','quema transantiago', 'matapaco', '#matapaco', '#chiledesperto','#piñeraculiao', '#renunciapiñera', 'plaza de la dignidad' ,'#chaopiñera', '#primeralinea' ,'incendio iglesia', '#piensaprensa','#chileoculto', '#plazadeladignidad', '#ElPeorGobiernoDeLaHistoria']
#dias anteriores a hoy
days = ['2019-10-16','2019-10-17', '2019-10-18','2019-10-19','2019-10-20','2019-10-21','2019-10-22','2019-10-23','2019-10-24','2019-10-25','2019-10-26','2019-10-27','2019-10-28','2019-10-29','2019-10-30','2019-10-31','2019-11-01','2019-11-02','2019-11-03','2019-11-04','2019-11-05','2019-11-06','2019-11-07','2019-11-08','2019-11-09','2019-11-10','2019-11-11','2019-11-12','2019-11-13','2019-11-14','2019-11-15','2019-11-16','2019-11-17','2019-11-18','2019-11-19','2019-11-20','2019-11-21','2019-11-22','2019-11-23','2019-11-24','2019-11-25','2019-11-26','2019-11-27','2019-11-28','2019-11-29','2019-11-30','2019-12-01','2019-12-02','2019-12-03','2019-12-04','2019-12-05','2019-12-06','2019-12-07','2019-12-07','2019-12-08','2019-12-09','2019-12-10','2019-12-11','2019-12-12','2019-12-13','2019-12-14','2019-12-15','2019-12-16','2019-12-17','2019-12-18','2019-12-19','2019-12-20','2019-12-21','2019-12-22','2019-12-23','2019-12-24','2019-12-25','2019-12-26','2019-12-27','2019-12-28','2019-12-29','2019-12-30','2019-12-31','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10','2020-01-11','2020-01-12','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15','2020-01-16','2020-01-17','2020-01-18','2020-01-19','2020-01-20','2020-01-21','2020-01-22','2020-01-23','2020-01-24','2020-01-25','2020-01-26']


text_tweets = []
for keyword in keywords:
    for day in days:
        # Creation of query object
        since_date = day
        #hasta mañana para que tome el dia de hoy solamente
        until_date = (day + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        tweetCriteria = (got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(keyword).setSince(since_date).setUntil(until_date).setNear(region).setWithin(milles))
        #saque set max tweets
        tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
        text_tweets += [[tweet.date, tweet.text, keyword] for tweet in tweets]

        #desde hoy
        #count = 100
        region = "Santiago, Chile"
        milles = "10mi"

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(text_tweets, columns=['Datetime', 'Text', 'keyword'])
tweets_df.to_csv('tweets.csv', sep=',')
```

Se que de esta forma esta escrito como para que se cree un csv con los tweets. Lo que me gustaría en realidad es crear un csv con la cantidad de tweets.

Comment: ¿El csv tendria la fecha, la palabra clave y el numero de tweets para esa fecha y palabra clave? Es decir, por ejemplo una linea podría ser `27/01/2020,saqueo chile,37`

Comment: @FJSevilla eso es lo que me gustaría lograr. Y tal vez, una línea final que agrupe todas las palabras clave por fecha. Ejemplo: `27/01/2020,400`.

Answer (score 2):

El método `TweetManager.getTweets` retorna una lista con instancias de `Tweet` directamente, por lo que bastaría con usar `len()` sobre su salida para contar los tweets. Algo como:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import GetOldTweets3 as got
import pandas as pd



keywords = ['saqueo chile', 'vandalismo chile', 'delincuencia chile','ataque carabinero', 'ataque comisaria','ataque subcomisaria',' manifestacion chile', 'protesta chile', 'bomba molotov','coctel molotov', 'funa chile', 'incendio intencional','quema transantiago', 'matapaco', '#matapaco', '#chiledesperto','#piñeraculiao', '#renunciapiñera', 'plaza de la dignidad' ,'#chaopiñera', '#primeralinea' ,'incendio iglesia', '#piensaprensa','#chileoculto', '#plazadeladignidad', '#ElPeorGobiernoDeLaHistoria']
#dias anteriores a hoy
days = ['2019-10-16','2019-10-17', '2019-10-18','2019-10-19','2019-10-20','2019-10-21','2019-10-22','2019-10-23','2019-10-24','2019-10-25','2019-10-26','2019-10-27','2019-10-28','2019-10-29','2019-10-30','2019-10-31','2019-11-01','2019-11-02','2019-11-03','2019-11-04','2019-11-05','2019-11-06','2019-11-07','2019-11-08','2019-11-09','2019-11-10','2019-11-11','2019-11-12','2019-11-13','2019-11-14','2019-11-15','2019-11-16','2019-11-17','2019-11-18','2019-11-19','2019-11-20','2019-11-21','2019-11-22','2019-11-23','2019-11-24','2019-11-25','2019-11-26','2019-11-27','2019-11-28','2019-11-29','2019-11-30','2019-12-01','2019-12-02','2019-12-03','2019-12-04','2019-12-05','2019-12-06','2019-12-07','2019-12-07','2019-12-08','2019-12-09','2019-12-10','2019-12-11','2019-12-12','2019-12-13','2019-12-14','2019-12-15','2019-12-16','2019-12-17','2019-12-18','2019-12-19','2019-12-20','2019-12-21','2019-12-22','2019-12-23','2019-12-24','2019-12-25','2019-12-26','2019-12-27','2019-12-28','2019-12-29','2019-12-30','2019-12-31','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-01-08','2020-01-09','2020-01-10','2020-01-11','2020-01-12','2020-01-13','2020-01-14','2020-01-15','2020-01-16','2020-01-17','2020-01-18','2020-01-19','2020-01-20','2020-01-21','2020-01-22','2020-01-23','2020-01-24','2020-01-25','2020-01-26']
region = "Santiago, Chile"
milles = "10mi"

tweets_count = []
for keyword in keywords:
    for since_date in days:
        until_date = (datetime.strptime(since_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
                      + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        tweet_criteria = (got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(keyword)
                                                     .setSince(since_date)
                                                     .setUntil(until_date)
                                                     .setNear(region)
                                                     .setWithin(milles)
                                                     )
        tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweet_criteria)
        tweets_count.append((since_date, keyword, len(tweets)))

tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(tweets_count, columns=['Date', 'keyword', 'Count'])
tweets_df.to_csv('tweets.csv', sep=',')
```